# How to hide the PropertyTabs on the PropertyGrid?

Tags: .net, propertygrid

How can I hide the PropertyTabs on the PropertyGrid?

I tried `PropertyGrid1.PropertyTabs.Clear(PropertyTabScope.Component)` but this had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I just found it.

Simply use: `PropertyGrid1.ToolbarVisible=False`